# Can you run a JS if statement and for loop inside a line of JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, for-loop

I am very new to learning both Javascript and Jquery.

In the website I am creating I am trying to insert a Javascript if statement and a for loop in a line of JQuery. The last confirm does not run. I suspect it is the if statement that is causing the issue. How can I fix this? Here is how my code looks like.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button3").click(function() {
        var lastname = $('#lastnameresponse').val();
        confirm("You're last name is" + " " + lastname);
        if (userResponse = "girl") {
            for (var i = 0; i <= girlnames.length; i++) {
                confirm("Your future daughter's name is" + " " + random + " " + randomagain + " " + lastname);
            })
    });
```

Comment: This does not look like complete code. What is `userResponse` ?

Comment: `userResponse = "girl"` assigns `"girl"` to `userResponse`. Use `==` or `===`. Same error you previously made: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17002680/139010

Comment: You have a stray parenthesis after your for loop as well.

Comment: I did not include the section where I defined userResponse. I fixed the comparison operator but the code still doesn't run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a *lot* that doesn't make much sense with your code.

First, what is `userResponse`?  Where does this get defined and where is it set?  Have you verified under a debugger that it is indeed *equal* to "girl"?

Second, you probably meant to use a *comparison equals* not an *assignment equals* here:

```
if (userResponse = "girl") { // This should be ==
```

However, this should not prevent the block from running.  In fact, it will force the block to *always* run since "girl" is true-ish.

Third, what is `girlnames`?  Is it an array?  Where is this defined?  Have you verified it indeed contains valid items?

Lastly, I believe your `for` loop is incorrect:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= girlnames.length; i++) {
```

Should be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < girlnames.length; i++) {
```

Arrays start at 0, thus `girlnames[girlnames.length]` is not a valid item.

However, considering you don't *use* the `i` variable in your loop anywhere, again this should not *actually* cause any errors.

I would step through your code line by line using a script debugger (usually <kbd>F12</kbd> in modern browsers) and set a break point at:

```
var lastname = $('#lastnameresponse').val();
```

Then verified each line is behaving correctly.  If that still doesn't work, you'll need to post more of your code so we can get a better idea of what's going on.

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comment:

> Here is where the userResponse variable is defined:
>   $(document).ready(function(){ $("#girlimg").click(function() { var
>   userResponse = prompt("Confirm the gender you selected").toLowerCase;
>   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".LastName").offset().top },
>   2000);

It seems that `userResponse` gets declared within the click handler for the `#girlimg` tag:

```
$("#girlimg").click(function() {
    // Everything declared here is local to this function
    var userResponse = confirm(); // local variable
});
```

Thus, it would not be accessible in the click handler for `.button3`.  You'll need to declare `userResponse` in a scope that is accessible to both functions.  Perhaps global (this is frowned upon in JavaScript) or within your `$(document).ready()` code, provided both click event handlers are defined within that block.

Comment: Hi Mike,

That's a mistake I have a tendency to make. However I did make that change and unfortunately the code still doesn't work. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Sure.  Where is `userResponse` defined?  Have you confirmed it is indeed equal to *girl"?  Where is `girlnames` defined?  Is it an array? Have you confirmed it has more than one value to iterate through?  Have you tried to debug this code using a script debugger?

Comment: girlnames is an array,

Here is where the userResponse variable is defined:

    $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#girlimg").click(function() {
 var userResponse = prompt("Confirm the gender you     selected").toLowerCase;
       $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(".LastName").offset().top
     }, 2000);

Comment: @user2466886 - Judging by your comment, it seems `userResponse` is local to that click handler.  It would not be accessible outside that function.

Answer (score 2):

First: it's `Your` not `You're` :)

Secondly, `userResponse` is undefined. Maybe it's defined somewhere else.

For comparison, use `==` operator.

Are you sure is that what you want to do? I see you also have `confirm` there.
Use `confirm` like this:

```
$(".button3").click(function() {
    var lastname = $('#lastnameresponse').val();
    // confirm() returns true or false, depending on the clicked button
    is_confirmed = confirm("You're last name is" + " " +lastname);
    if (true == is_confirmed) {
        for (var i = 0; i <= girlnames.length; i++) {
            confirm ("Your future daughter's name is" + " " + random + " " + randomagain + " " +   lastname);
        }
    }
});
```

`girlnames` is also not defined here (maybe it's somewhere else). Same for `random` and `randomagain`

As for writing JavaScript "in" jQuery: there is no such question. jQuery is a library written in Javascript that provides useful functions to ease development.

Comment: I am still a little confused on how confirm works. Your suggestion did make the code run but it didn't get the last confirm (after the for loop) to run.

All of the other variables were defined previously.

Comment: The last `confirm()` does not work unless `girlnames` is defined as an array with at least one item. Read about `confirm` and arrays in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Following statement does not contain a proper JavaScript Comparison Operator

equals is written ==

```
if (userResponse = "girl") {
```

for reference look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to close some arrows, any way when you put :

```
if (userResponse ="girl"){...}
```

you set userResponse variable to "girl", and that passes the value to the variable only
to check in the userResponse is equal to "girl" you should put

```
if (userResponse =="girl")
```

your final code will look like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$(".button3").click(function() {
var lastname = $('#lastnameresponse').val();
confirm("You're last name is" + " " +lastname);
if (userResponse ="girl") {
    for (var i = 0; i <= girlnames.length; i++) {
    confirm ("Your future daughter's name is" + " " + random + " " + randomagain + " " +   lastname);
    }}}
)
});
```

p.s:you forgot to close too many arrows